# Scrape data from WebSocket with C# .Net

Tags: c#, websocket, clientwebsocket

I need to scrape data from a websocket "just one time".

I mean that I don't need to get continuosly data from the source but I need
to get the data one time and exit from the elaboration.

I don't need Async task, I just need to use it like a simple API.

I'm struggling with web search but I didn't find any solution.

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are struggling to find such code as websocket is almost a bi-directional protocol, not really for a RPC style.
But to answer your need, you could certainly use a library such as [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) . Your code to send a command text and receive back a return message would look like this :

```
using System;
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace Example
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      using (var ws = new WebSocket ("ws://YOUR_URI_HERE")) {
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            Console.WriteLine ("It's ok I got my answer back : " + e.Data);

        ws.Connect ();
        ws.Send ("COMMAND FOR THE SERVER");
        Console.ReadKey (true);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that code will help you to get started.

Comment: Does websocket-shap support additional headers ?

Comment: Thanks for you precius help.
Do you know if websocket-shap support additional headers ?
I need to add User-Agent as header, otherwise the websocket doesn't accept connections...

Comment: Hello, you could not change the user-agent but if you grab the code of the library, you could make it as a poperty or hardcode your user-agent (for this you have to change the code in this class : https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/blob/master/websocket-sharp/HttpRequest.cs)